# Prestashop 1.6 - Disable Payment Accepted email when order amount is 0(zero)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

My requirement is to disable sending email to the customer when the order amount is zero.

I am new to Prestashop and not able to understand in which class or controller I have to put this condition. I found some references like : https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/175669-disable-order-emails/
But this is for disable all the emails.

Any help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In ***Classes/PaymentModule.Php***

You need to add the condition above these lines. (Line number around 791). This part sends confirmation email to the customer.

```
if (Validate::isEmail($this->context->customer->email))
    Mail::Send(
    (int)$order->id_lang,
    'order_conf',
    Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$order->id_lang),
    $data,
    $this->context->customer->email,
    $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname,
    null,
    null,
    $file_attachement,
    null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$order->id_shop
);
```

Condition can be like

```
if($order->total_paid>0)
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I tried this condition but it stops the "Order Confirmation" email not the "Payment Accepted" email.

Comment: You can disable it from admin panel itself. Go to **Orders->Order status**
uncheck _send email to customer_.